# Subquery between three objects

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have three different models Department ,subdepartments and employee

```
@interface Department : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<SubDepartment> *subDepartments; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Employee> *employees; 

@end

@interface SubDepartment : RLMObject

@property NSString *name; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<Employee> *employees; 

@end 

@interface Employee : RLMObject

@property NSString *department;
@property NSString *email;
@property NSString *firstname;
@property NSString *lastname;
@property NSString *fullname;
@property NSString *imgUrl;
@property NSString *imgWall;
@property NSString *nickname;

@end
```

I want to search which department of employee has contains "a" in their first name and last name and also want to search through subdepartment employees whose name contains "a" in their first name and last name.

I was trying to do like that.

```
RLMResults *subdepartments = [SubDepartment objectsWhere:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.firstname contains '%@' OR $e.lastname contains '%@' OR $e.fullname contains '%@' OR $e.nickname contains '%@').@count > 0",searchText,searchText,searchText,searchText]];

    NSMutableArray *subDepartmentNames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (SubDepartment *subDepartment in sections)
    {
        [subDepartmentNames addObject:subDepartment.name];
    }

    RLMResults *departments = [Department objectsWhere:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(employees, $e, $e.firstname contains '%@' OR $e.lastname contains '%@' OR $e.fullname contains '%@' OR $e.nickname contains '%@').@count > 0",searchText,searchText,searchText,searchText]];

    RLMResults<Department *> *filteredDepartments = [departments objectsWhere:
                                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(subDepartments, $d, $d.name IN '%@').@count > 0",sectionNames]];
```

Comment: Please show an example of your own attempt of solving the problem.

Comment: I updated my example. @VadimShkaberda

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not need to use subquery. More simply, you can use `ANY` in query like the following:

```
[Department objectsWhere:
    @"ANY employees.firstname CONTAINS %@ OR ANY employees.lastname CONTAINS %@ OR ANY subDepartments.employees.firstname CONTAINS %@ OR ANY subDepartments.employees.lastname CONTAINS %@", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];
```

But I think using inverse relationships is more easier. In Realm, inverse relationships is defined with `RLMLinkingObjects`.
You can add inverse relationships to `User` class as follows:

```
@interface Employee : RLMObject

...

@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *departments;
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *subDepartments;

@end

@implementation User

+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{@"departments": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Department.class propertyName:@"employees"],
             @"subDepartments": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:SubDepartment.class propertyName:@"employees"]};
}

@end
```

Then you can get departments and sections where the user belongs to from `User`'s property, like the following:

```
RLMResults *employees = [Employee objectsWhere:@"firstname CONTAINS %@ OR lastname CONTAINS %@" , searchText, searchText];
for (Employee *employee in employees) {
    NSLog(@"%@", employee.departments);
    NSLog(@"%@", employee.subDepartments);
}
```